# Why XPATH count function returns a double instead of int?

Tags: c#, xpath

The following fragment of code produces an ***InvalidCastException***.

```cs
    static int XPathCount()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(
        @"<root>
             <item>value1</item>
             <item>value2</item>
             <item>value3</item>
          </root>");

        var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
        var expression = navigator.Compile("count(//item)");
        var count = navigator.Evaluate(expression);
        return (int) count;
    }
```

I was surprised of this behavior so I look the *count()* function into the [XPATH specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count):

> The count function returns the number of nodes in the argument node-set.

So far so good but, what is a *number*? The answer is in the same specification:

> number (a floating-point number)

Apparently this has been fixed in [XPATH 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-count) to return an xs:integer but I still curious about this.

Does anyone knows why W3C decided to use a decimal number for the *count()* function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a decimal. In XPath 1.0 it's an IEEE double-precision floating point number, in XPath 2.0 it's an integer.

XPath 1.0 has a single numeric type for the same reason Javascript does: in a weakly, dynamically typed language it makes considerable sense. Also, at the time XPath 1.0 was designed, Javascript was considered the primary candidate for the host language, which is why the data types are aligned with Javascript.

If you've only got one numeric type available, then that's what count() has to return.

Answer (score 1):

```
Does anyone knows why W3C decided to use a decimal number for the count() function?
```

I assume it returns `double` as its more versatile, for example if your Xml contains product prices and it only returned `int` you would never get a correct sum of price.

and looking at the [source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFXspW7/ndp/fx/src/Xml/System/Xml/XPath/Internal/NumberFunctions@cs/1/NumberFunctions@cs) it seems everything returns double, even count, I guess because all other function would require this except count, but there could be some situations where count would need a double, not sure where but it could.

Example:

```
double totalPrice = (double)navigator.Evaluate("sum(descendant::Product/price)");


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Products>
    <Product>
        <name>Product1</name>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </Product>
     <Product>
        <name>Product2</name>
        <price>12.99</price>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

If it only returned `int` it would make it impossible to do the above functions. And since you can simply cast `double` to `int` it makes perfect sense to use `double` for count

Comment: I see your point. Maybe XPATH specification tried to be as neutral as possible related to types and defined a Number to cover all possible results.