# Most efficient way to count nodes using XPath in Python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, python-requests, scrape

In Python, how could I count the nodes using XPath?
For example, using [this webpage](http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/item/587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals) and this code:

```
from lxml import html, etree
import requests
url = "http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/item/587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals"
r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
count = tree.xpath('count(//*[@id="body"])')
print count
```

It prints 1. But it has 5 `div` nodes.
Please explain this to me, and how can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints 1 (or 1.0) because there is just one such element with `id="body"` in the HTML file you are fetching.

I downloaded the file and verified this is the case. E.g.:

```
$ curl -O http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/item/587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals
```

Grabs a file `587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals`

```
$ grep --count 'id="body"' 587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals
```

Answers 1. Just to be extra sure, I hand-searched in the file as well, using vi. Just the one!

Perhaps you are looking for another `div` node? One with a different `id`?

**Update:** By the way, XPath and other HTML/XML parsing is pretty challenging to work with. A lot of bad data out there, and a lot of complex markup, times the complexity of the retrieval, parsing, and traversal process. You will probably be running your tests and trials a lot of times. It will be a lot faster if you do not "hit the net" for every one of them. Cache the live results. Raw code looks something like this:

```
from lxml import html, etree
import requests

filepath = "587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals"
try:
    contents = open(filepath).read()
    print "(reading cached copy)"
except IOError:
    url = "http://intelligencesquaredus.org/debates/past-debates/item/587-islam-is-dominated-by-radicals"
    print "(getting file from the net; please stand by)"
    r = requests.get(url)
    contents = r.content
tree = html.fromstring(contents)
count = tree.xpath('count(//*[@id="body"])')
print count
```

But you can simplify a lot of that by using a generic caching front-end to `requests`, such as [requests-cache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache).  Happy parsing!

Comment: Because XPath 1.0 does things that way. XPath 2.0 will return the more-expected integer result. [See this question for a deeper explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960497/why-xpath-count-function-returns-a-double-instead-of-int)